# How to access user information from an array list that stores user uids in Flutter using Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Okay, so in my cloud firestore, I have a system set up where a user can create or join a group.  This is done by a unique groupId being created for that user, which is used as the document path for a collection called groups where information for that group is stored, most importantly being the member list.  So far I store users by their uid.  However, I've gotten to the point where soon I want to display member's information like member names, photos, etc.  The problem is that I do not know how to properly access information inside a firestore array, in this case being the uids from which I can use those uids as a path to get user display names, and other stuff.

Here is a photo showing the Groups collection, with teh groupId path and the member array:
[image]

Here is my attempt to access the member array:

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<List<String>> getGroupMembers() async {
    final CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('UserNames');

    final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;

    final result = await users.doc(uid).get();

    final groupId = result.data()['groupId'];

    final CollectionReference groups = firestore.collection('Groups');

    final groupMembersResult = await groups.doc(groupId).get();

    return groupMembersResult.data()['members'];
  }
```

What I have done here is getting the unique user uid, and from that access the user's groupId value.  I use that groupId value as a pathway in the Groups Collection to acess that specific group's information.  How can I specifically access the contents inside of the member array?

Comment: Can you please add the output you get from `getGroupMembers()` method?

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi Okay, I'll get it to you in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access an array list as you do it in an object that contains an array. In your case you would have something like  :

```
Future<List<String>> getGroupMembers() async {
  final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  final currentUser = [];
  final groups = [];
  // Get User document
  await firestore
      .collection('UserNames')
      .document(uid)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    currentUser.add(snapshot.data);
  });
  // Get groupeId from currentUser Data
  final groupId = currentUser[0]['groupId'];

  // Get groupe Document
  await firestore
      .collection('Groups')
      .document(groupId)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    groups.add(snapshot.data);
  });

  return groups[0]['members'];

}
```